# What effect does the base-tag have on svg:s with xlink:href?

Tags: html, svg

I'm including svg:s in my markup using xlink:href:

```
<svg class="questionTitleIcon">
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-questionmark"></use>
</svg>
```

#icon-questionmark is defined

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="icon-questionmark" viewBox="0 0 60 61" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns"><!-- Generator: Sketch 3.4.1 (15681) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch --><title>Slice 1</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc><defs></defs><g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage"><g id="icon-invoicing-1" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup"><path d="M59.9827338,30.6427143 C59.9827338,14.2078571 46.5638849,0.884857143 30.0107914,0.884857143 C13.4581295,0.884857143 0.0392805755,14.2078571 0.0392805755,30.6427143 C0.0392805755,47.0775714 13.4581295,60.4005714 30.0107914,60.4005714 C46.5638849,60.4005714 59.9827338,47.0775714 59.9827338,30.6427143" id="Fill-1" fill="#FFBB2F" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path><path d="M32.7333898,38.383 C33.4633898,39.1 33.8283898,40.003 33.8283898,41.091 C33.8283898,42.18 33.4633898,43.082 32.7333898,43.799 C32.0023898,44.516 31.0933898,44.874 30.0053898,44.874 C28.9163898,44.874 28.0203898,44.516 27.3173898,43.799 C26.6143898,43.082 26.2623898,42.18 26.2623898,41.091 C26.2623898,40.003 26.6143898,39.1 27.3173898,38.383 C28.0203898,37.667 28.9163898,37.308 30.0053898,37.308 C31.0933898,37.308 32.0023898,37.667 32.7333898,38.383 Z" id="Path" stroke="#6C4B00" stroke-width="2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path><path d="M22.0223898,23.022 C22.0223898,23.022 22.4993898,19.883 24.0523898,18.329 C25.6053898,16.777 27.7353898,16 30.4433898,16 C31.7433898,16 32.9053898,16.193 33.9273898,16.577 C34.9493898,16.963 35.8193898,17.507 36.5353898,18.21 C37.2523898,18.914 37.7963898,19.743 38.1683898,20.699 C38.5393898,21.654 38.7253898,22.69 38.7253898,23.805 C38.7253898,24.601 38.6393898,25.298 38.4663898,25.895 C38.2943898,26.492 38.0623898,27.037 37.7703898,27.528 C37.4773898,28.019 37.1463898,28.464 36.7743898,28.862 L36.4023898,29.26 C35.9503898,29.676 35.2333898,30.297 34.8093898,30.641 C34.8093898,30.641 34.8093898,30.641 34.4653898,30.932 C34.1193898,31.225 33.8083898,31.53 33.5293898,31.848 C33.2503898,32.167 33.1113901,32.3135647 32.8723898,32.884 C32.6333895,33.4544353 32.6333898,34.305 32.6333898,34.437 C32.6333898,34.568 31.7333898,34.675 30.6333898,34.675 L29.0583898,34.675 C27.9583898,34.675 27.0583898,34.326 27.0583898,33.899 C27.0583898,33.472 27.1773898,31.749 27.4173898,31.151 C27.6563898,30.554 27.9603898,30.017 28.3323898,29.539 C28.7043898,29.061 29.1153898,28.623 29.5673898,28.225 L30.0183898,27.826 C30.5143898,27.432 31.4163898,26.701 32.0223898,26.201 C32.0223898,26.201 32.0223898,26.201 32.4743898,25.736 C32.9253898,25.272 33.1513898,24.734 33.1513898,24.123 C33.1513898,23.433 32.9323898,22.836 32.4943898,22.331 C32.0553898,21.827 31.3323898,21.575 30.3233898,21.575 C29.3143898,21.575 28.5323898,21.867 27.9743898,22.451 C27.7887231,22.6456667 27.9743896,22.4510002 27.4173899,23.2842646 C26.8603902,24.1175289 26.2383898,24.999 25.1383898,24.999 L23.7223898,24.999 C22.6223898,24.999 21.8573898,24.109 22.0223898,23.022 Z" id="Path" stroke="#6C4B00" stroke-width="2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path></g></g></symbol>
</svg>
```

This works fine in Chrome.

In firefox, on any other url than "/", if I have a base-tag in my header, the items are not found, here is an example of the base-tag

Why is this and what can be done about it?

Comment: This is a chrome bug. <funcIRI>#element should be equal to <baseURI>#element. Using the <base> tag you do change the baseURI of the doc. FF is right here. To avoid it, use absolute urls instead of relative ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kaiido said, if you have to use a `<base>` element, then you will need to change all your `xlink:href` and `url(#foo)` references to absolute URLs.  For example:

```
xlink:href="/path/to/my.svg#icon-questionmark"
```